# python selenium - extract link address from hidden button

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to extract the link address from the hidden button that appears when I hover the mouse over it. The code for this button cannot find the link address at all. Below is the relevant code.

```
<div><button type="button" class="ant-btn hover-btn btn-open-detail" ant-click-animating-without-extra-node="false"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path d="M18 13v6a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h6"></path><polyline points="15 3 21 3 21 9"></polyline><line x1="10" y1="14" x2="21" y2="3"></line></svg><span>상품정보</span></button><button type="button" class="ant-btn hover-btn btn-generate-link"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path d="M10 13a5 5 0 0 0 7.54.54l3-3a5 5 0 0 0-7.07-7.07l-1.72 1.71"></path><path d="M14 11a5 5 0 0 0-7.54-.54l-3 3a5 5 0 0 0 7.07 7.07l1.71-1.71"></path></svg><span>링크 생성</span></button></div>
```

I want to link to the site, but it is meaningless because I can't see it without logging in.

```
prourl = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/section[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/button[1]")))


for u in prourl:
    print(WebDriverWait(u, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "a"))).get_attribute('href'))
```

I tried this once, but it also failed. help

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: This site cannot be viewed without logging in.

Comment: I understand. But currently your question is missing a minimal debugging details

Comment: <BUTTON> tags usually fire some javascript function which may or may not send an ajax request and then update the DOM.  (So there is no link to extract there...)  You can trace  event handler using the browser's dev tools.